# High Level Assembly (HLA) Programming

Tags: hla

I'm having trouble figuring out this assignment that I have in HLA.

Write a program to produce a number table as described here. This table should be built from a single integer value provided by the user. The program will display a square 5X5 of various numbers.  The entered number should appear in an X like pattern across the table, diagonally across the table.  Every other spot besides the X pattern should be filled with a number.  Those excess numbers should start with one bigger than the entered number and increment by one for every additional excess number used.

For example, the following output should be produced when the user inputs the starting value 15:

Gimme a starting value: 15

15 16 17 18 15

19 15 20 15 21

22 23 15 24 25

26 15 27 15 28

15 29 30 31 15

For example, the following output should be produced when the user inputs the starting value 20:

Gimme a starting value: 20

20 21 22 23 20

24 20 25 20 26

27 28 20 29 30

31 20 32 20 33

20 34 35 36 20

(Hint:  Please don't worry about the formatting of the table, if it doesn't exactly match mine above.  The goal is to practice with HLA and we really don't know enough to get the spacing just perfect...)

I have the following code that I've tried but can't figure it out. I am a totally new in HLA programming.

```
program tableX;

#include( "stdlib.hhf" );

// Initiate variable
static
tblX : int32 := 0; // tblX value

// Columns for row 1
column1 : int32 := 0;


// Start the program
begin tableX;

// Ask the user to input a value
stdout.put("Gimme a starting value: ");

// Get the user's inputted value
stdin.get(tblX);

// Get the value into the register EAX
mov(tblX, EAX);
mov(0, EBX);

mov(column1, EAX);
mov(1, EBX);

// Add the values
add(EAX, EBX);
add(1, tblX);

add(EAX, EBX);
add(1, column1);

// Put the value back into the tblX variable
mov(EBX, tblX);

// 1st row
stdout.put(tblX);
stdout.put(column1);




// End the program
end tableX;
```

I'm literally having trouble on figuring out how to display it in 5x5. Do I need to add more variables for columns for each rows. I only added one column for testing purposes. If you can help with this, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

***ENVIRONMENT***

- HLA (High Level Assembler - HLABE back end, POLINK linker)
  Version 2.16 build 4413 (prototype)
- Windows 10

***NOTE***

- There are several ways to go about solving this problem and this example could be improved.

***EXAMPLE***

```
program tableX;
#include( "stdlib.hhf" );

// Initiate variable
static
    OriginalVal: int32 := 0; // Original value
    DuplicateVal: int32 := 0; // Duplicate value for incrementing
    XPatternArray: int32[9] := [0, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24]; // Indexes for X pattern

// Start the program
begin tableX;

    // Ask the user to input a value
    stdout.put("Gimme a starting value: ");

    // Get the user's inputted value
    stdin.get(OriginalVal);
    mov(OriginalVal, DuplicateVal);

    // Build and Print Table
    xor(EDX, EDX);
    for ( mov(0, EBX); EBX <= 24; inc(EBX) ) do

        mov(EBX, EAX);
        mov(5, ECX);
        idiv(CL);
        if ( AH == 0 ) then
            stdout.newln();
        endif;

        if ( EBX == XPatternArray[EDX*4] ) then
            stdout.put(OriginalVal, " ");
            inc(EDX);

        else
            inc(DuplicateVal);
            stdout.put(DuplicateVal, " ");

        endif;

    endfor;

// End the program
end tableX;
```